# Plot color of the plot R

Tags: r, plot, background-color

I want to plot in R, and change the background color. I bet its quite simple, but I have tried methods listed both in here and on google, but however I try it, at the end of the plot, the plot itself disappears, while i get the background color i am looking for.

For example, this code:

```
a = 18
b = 100
E_menn=rep(0,b+1)
E_kvinner=rep(0,b+1) 
for(i in a:b){
    E_menn[i+1]=gompakmean(theta_menn[10,],i,h=1)
    E_kvinner[i+1]=gompakmean(theta_kvinner[10,],i,h=1)
    plot(a:b,E_menn[a:b+1],type="l", xlab="Alder",ylab="Forventet       leveaar",main="Forventet levetid")
    lines(a:b,E_kvinner[a:b+1], type="l", col="red")
    legend("topright", c("menn","kvinner"), col =   c("black","red"),cex=0.9,lty=1)
}
```

I have tried writing

```
plot.new()
rect(par("usr")[1], par("usr")[3], par("usr")[2], par("usr")[4], col     = "ivory")
```

both before the loop, and within the loope. The background color i want is "ivory".

Is there something im missing?
Thankful for all answers

Regards, J

Comment: `par(bg = "ivory")` before the `plot` call will do it

Comment: In general , THE big thing to remember about plots in R is if you want to change anything you've got check the help of the `par` funciton

Comment: that did work @dickoa, but then the whole window became ivory. I just want the plot-box to become ivory-colored, and hence the main text and labels to be on white background.

Comment: This strategy should work: `plot(x <- runif(10), y <- runif(10), type = "n"); do.call(rect, as.list(c(par("usr")[c(1, 3, 2, 4)], col = "grey90"))); points(x, y)
`. You may want to post a reproducible example.

Comment: I just marked this as a duplicate of another question I answered a couple of years ago. Oddly enough, there doesn't seem to be any par setting for this, maybe because the graphics engine's authors think see it as "easy enough" to do something like what @lukeA or I suggested...

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thank you for the link to the other question. I tried something that was written there, got it to work!